JupyterHub Gitlab Oauth integration
I'm trying to integrate JupyterHub with GitLab using OAuth. When I look at the JupyterHub logs, I continually encounter two errors: "400 Bad Request OAuth state missing from cookies" and "Error fetching 599 POST http://172.19.238.185:9080/oauth/token: HTTP 599: Connection timed out after 20001 milliseconds."
I am currently using WSL2, and I have attached my environment and code details. Please help.
[ jupyterhub error log ]
[E 2024-05-09 08:07:31.418 JupyterHub oauth2:653] Error fetching 599 POST http://172.19.238.185:9080/oauth/token: HTTP 599: Connection timed out after 20001 milliseconds
[E 2024-05-09 08:07:31.418 JupyterHub web:1875] Uncaught exception GET /hub/oauth_callback?code=6266fd4b33deec46e72239e1f876d3a4751ab968682d9c67740f7d916f98c0f4&state=eyJzdGF0ZV9pZCI6ICIxMWE4NjNkNzJmMWQ0OGM4OWRlZThhMjFkYjdjOTEzNSJ9 (::ffff:192.168.240.1)
    HTTPServerRequest(protocol='https', host='www.gitlab.example.com:8443', method='GET', uri='/hub/oauth_callback?code=6266fd4b33deec46e72239e1f876d3a4751ab968682d9c67740f7d916f98c0f4&state=eyJzdGF0ZV9pZCI6ICIxMWE4NjNkNzJmMWQ0OGM4OWRlZThhMjFkYjdjOTEzNSJ9', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::ffff:192.168.240.1')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1790, in _execute
        result = await result
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/oauthenticator/oauth2.py", line 210, in get
        user = await self.login_user()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/jupyterhub/handlers/base.py", line 928, in login_user
        authenticated = await self.authenticate(data)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/jupyterhub/auth.py", line 493, in get_authenticated_user
        authenticated = await maybe_future(self.authenticate(handler, data))
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/oauthenticator/oauth2.py", line 1029, in authenticate
        token_info = await self.get_token_info(handler, access_token_params)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/oauthenticator/oauth2.py", line 874, in get_token_info
        token_info = await self.httpfetch(
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/oauthenticator/oauth2.py", line 688, in httpfetch
        return await self.fetch(
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/oauthenticator/oauth2.py", line 654, in fetch
        raise e
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/oauthenticator/oauth2.py", line 633, in fetch
        resp = await self.http_client.fetch(req, **kwargs)
    tornado.curl_httpclient.CurlError: HTTP 599: Connection timed out after 20001 milliseconds

[I 2024-05-09 08:07:31.419 JupyterHub _xsrf_utils:125] Setting new xsrf cookie for b'None:NgfnePWlIjz1DeW9VtMxA7IUHWMF_A4-VC0vzKbXkbs=' {'path': '/hub/', 'max_age': 3600}
[E 2024-05-09 08:07:31.439 JupyterHub log:184] {
      "X-Forwarded-Host": "www.gitlab.example.com:8443",
      "X-Forwarded-Proto": "https",
      "X-Forwarded-Port": "8443",
      "X-Forwarded-For": "::ffff:192.168.240.1",
      "Cookie": "_xsrf=[secret]; preferred_language=[secret]; oauthenticator-state=[secret]; known_sign_in=[secret]; _gitlab_session=[secret]",
      "Accept-Language": "ko,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br, zstd",
      "Referer": "https://www.gitlab.example.com/",
      "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
      "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
      "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-site",
      "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7",
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/123.0.0.0",
      "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
      "Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform": "\"Windows\"",
      "Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile": "?0",
      "Sec-Ch-Ua": "\"Microsoft Edge\";v=\"123\", \"Not:A-Brand\";v=\"8\", \"Chromium\";v=\"123\"",
      "Connection": "keep-alive",
      "Host": "www.gitlab.example.com:8443"
    }
[E 2024-05-09 08:07:31.439 JupyterHub log:192] 500 GET /hub/oauth_callback?code=[secret]&state=[secret] (@::ffff:192.168.240.1) 20023.17ms
[W 2024-05-09 08:08:43.135 JupyterHub web:1873] 400 GET /hub/oauth_callback?code=6266fd4b33deec46e72239e1f876d3a4751ab968682d9c67740f7d916f98c0f4&state=eyJzdGF0ZV9pZCI6ICIxMWE4NjNkNzJmMWQ0OGM4OWRlZThhMjFkYjdjOTEzNSJ9 (::ffff:192.168.240.1): OAuth state missing from cookies
[W 2024-05-09 08:08:43.136 JupyterHub log:192] 400 GET /hub/oauth_callback?code=[secret]&state=[secret] (@::ffff:192.168.240.1) 1.64ms

[ hosts ]
172.19.238.185 www.gitlab.example.com

[ docker-compose.yml ]
version: '3.8'

services:
  jupyterhub:
    image: jupyterhub1
    container_name: jupyterhub
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8443:443'
    command: jupyterhub  
    stdin_open: true  
    tty: true  
    depends_on:
      - gitlab 
    volumes:
      - ../openssl/server.crt:/etc/jupyterhub/ssl/server.crt
      - ../openssl/server.key:/etc/jupyterhub/ssl/server.key
      - ./jupyterhub_config.py:/srv/jupyterhub/jupyterhub_config.py
    networks:
      - internal_network


  gitlab:
    image: gitlab
    container_name: gitlab
    restart: always
    hostname: www.gitlab.example.com
    ports:
      - '443:443'  
      - '9080:80'  
      - '10022:22'  
    volumes:
      - ./gitlab.rb:/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
      - /var/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab
      - /var/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab
      - /var/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab
      - ../openssl/server.crt:/etc/gitlab/ssl/server.crt
      - ../openssl/server.key:/etc/gitlab/ssl/server.key
    networks:
      - internal_network

networks:
  internal_network:
    driver: bridge



    

[ gitlab.rb ]
gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 10022
external_url 'https://www.gitlab.example.com'
nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/server.crt"
nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/server.key"
 

[jupyterhub_config.py]
from oauthenticator.gitlab import GitLabOAuthenticator

c = get_config()  #noqa

c.Spawner.default_url = '/lab'


c.JupyterHub.authenticator_class = GitLabOAuthenticator
c.GitLabOAuthenticator.oauth_access_token_url = 'https://www.gitlab.example.com/oauth/token'
c.GitLabOAuthenticator.oauth_callback_url = 'https://www.gitlab.example.com:8443/hub/oauth_callback'
c.GitLabOAuthenticator.client_id = '75332de9e109185387a2d1224f715b93eeea0662b455e162e7922b38b023bdcb'
c.GitLabOAuthenticator.client_secret = 'gloas-16d6fa103ff0c4a3d7c0b4a9b1e5b167645632ac2475d891f9f4654103ea45ac'
c.GitLabOAuthenticator.gitlab_host = 'https://www.gitlab.example.com'

c.JupyterHub.port = 443
c.JupyterHub.ssl_key = '/etc/jupyterhub/ssl/server.key'
c.JupyterHub.ssl_cert = '/etc/jupyterhub/ssl/server.crt'

c.Authenticator.admin_users = {'admin'}
c.PAMAuthenticator.admin_groups = {'masterG'}
                                                                                                                    


                                                                                                                    

